# sound issue in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: sound

My system is VAIO VPCEG28FN. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and my sound card is HDA Intel PCH , Chip: Conexant ID 506e. I have a problem and it is that sound plays through the speakers and the headset simultaneously. Also the headset is not shown in Alsa mixer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I just upgraded my ALSA driver to 1.0.25. To do this, just follow the method given in the link:

- http://monespaceperso.org/blog-en/2010/05/02/upgrade-alsa-1-0-23-on-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-10-04/

In this, just change the ALSA version from 1.0.23 to 1.0.25 in all the steps.